# asterisk originate an automated call outside playing a sound file when answered

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to set up a autodialer configuration with call files where we call outside and when answered to have a sound played back. If possible I would like to have the ability to set the origination CallerID.

So far what I have managed is to create a call file wihout any context in and it calls out but on the destination the origination number shows asterisk.

the call file have this format:

```
Channel: SIP/trunk/destination_number
Maxretries: 3
RetryTime: 60
Application: Playback
Extension: destination_number
Data: soundfile
```

I would also like to have the possibility to try different trunks if possible.

Comment: So what is question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the `CallerId` directive, eg:

```
CallerID: "name" <number>
```

Place that into your call file and you should be good to go (assuming your SIP provider allows you to set variable caller IDs).

Comment: That fixed the CallerID thing. Thank you